# GParted shows hard drive as two drives of equal storage capacity

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, xfce

I'm trying to format my Xbox One S hard drive with GParted. It appears to show two 900GB disks as `/dev/sdc` and `/dev/sdd` instead of one 900GB disk, on top of that.

`/dev/sdc` :

[image: /dev/sdc]

`/dev/sdd` :

[image: /dev/sdd]

The first disk had been formatted, while the other is completely made of unallocated space and constantly throws I/O errors when being accessed or even closed by GParted.

All of a sudden, the `/dev/sdd` drive vanished. Why did that happen?